# how to delete duplicate content and copy the value in the last column in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Please have a look at the format belwow , i want to delete the duplicate rows and copy the last column content to its original row.

In the below picture, i want to delete duplicate contents row A4 and copy the content of C4 life to C3 so that C3 becomes - god,life . To delete the row, the content of A and B should be the same. In third row, A3,B3 ,A4,B4 are same so we can delete it.

In seventh and Eight row ,A7 and A8 are the same but B7 and B8 are different , so it shouldn't be deleted.

But in Eight row , A8,A9 and B8,B9 are also the same so ninth Row A9 should be deleted and C8 becomes Marriage,Beauty

Thanks a lot!

[here is the excel image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRj0s.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about writing a quick macro to do this? Iterate through the rows and check if A(i) == A(i+1). If so, set C(i) = C(i) + "," + C(i + 1) and repeat until iterated through all of the rows?